# Channel Form File Upload Question

Tags: safecracker, channel, file-uploads, safecracker-file

I don't think I quite understand from the EE documentation how to upload a file using a Channel Form (previously SafeCracker).

I would like to upload my sermon audio files into the sermons upload path (http://example.com/sermon-files/). The file channel field I have is called {sermon_file}.

Here is the code from the documentation:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="my_field_name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_directory" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_hidden_file" value="{my_field_name}{file_name}{/my_field_name}" />
</div><!--/.form-group-->
```

This assumes that the {exp:channel:form channel="sermons"} tag is before all this code and contains a submit button.

My question is, what the heck do I put in these "my_field_name" placeholders?

Appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be the field name you gave your file field which you said was `{sermon_file}`. Or you could always just replace all that with `{field:sermon_file}`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="sermon_file" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sermon_file_directory" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sermon_file_hidden_file" value="{sermon_file}{file_name}{/sermon_file}" />
</div><!--/.form-group-->
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The {field:sermon_file} thing was the thing that actually worked.